# How to fetch vimeo links of video >100

Tags: fetch, vimeo-api

I understand Vimeo-API can fetch links of only 100 videos. We have 200+ videos in Vimeo and would like to fetch their links dynamically thru Cron job. Vimeo told us it can do only for 100 videos. Is that true ? is there anyway we can fetch the links of all videos > 100. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Suresh Agrawal

Answer (score 2):

Nope. From the Vimeo API documentation pages, each page of a response can have a maximum of 100 objects/items returned. The only way to get more than that is to make additional requests, specifying the maximum number of objects/items.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#using-the-pagination-parameter

Also, considering each video object can be quite large, you should use the `fields` parameter to only specify the metadata needed for your application. For instance, if you only need the video link from the response, then your request uri might look like this:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?fields=uri,link&page=1&per_page=100
```

See the documentation here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter

Comment: This is so important, as its crazy how much data they return by default, they would be wasting more resources on all this spam being returned than they save by limiting results to 100 ! :p